# Material Ui select - Selected Item in Material Ui select component is showing empty

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am showing a form on click of button, as part of form i have implemented material Ui select item. 
I have included all this code in child component and onchange handler function is in parent component.
Ui and on change handler are working fine but the problem is select component is not showing selected menu item label. 
If i keep Option instead of MenuItem it is working

Here is the sandbox link 
[Sandboxcode link](https://codesandbox.io/s/o5yvnxvp05)

Comment: your sandbox link doesnt compile?

Comment: @G_S It is working . I just tried in incognito mode also

Comment: Ok It is working now. Let me check.

Comment: Your on change handler is a closure `handleSelectChange = event => name => {`
i.e it is not a function, rather a function which returns another function.

Your `setState` never gets called when you change the input.

Comment: @UtsavPatel Thats true. I modified code now but then also same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the state incorrectly:

```
this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value 
});
```

But according to your state structure you should wrap name-value object into *serviceRequest*:

```
this.setState({ 
     serviceRequest: {
         [event.target.name]: event.target.value }
      }
);
```

Comment: In your HomeComponent change Select value setting to 
value={props.values}.

Then in index.js change values to:

 `render() {
    const { serviceRequest: { selectedService : value} } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <HomeTemplate
          values={value}
          handleSelectChange={this.handleSelectChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }`

In your previous code, when you write 
`const selectedService = { serviceRequest } `
_selectedService_ will be an object
 `{
   selectedRequest: {}
`}. 
You don't need curly brackets there.

Comment: Sandbox doesnt have new changes :(

Comment: `const selectedService = serviceRequest;
    const values = selectedService; `
Just remove curly braces. They're unneeded here, cause it's ES6 syntax to create an object

Comment: `const b = '123';
const a = {b}`
Creates a as an object with 'b' property and b variable value:
`a = {
  b: '123'
`}

Comment: I created a new sandbox with fixes, check it https://codesandbox.io/s/rmqo0kwk3n?fontsize=14

Comment: You're welcome! I also edited HomeComponent a bit: `values={props.values}`, but you can return your old code if you need, just don't forget to also change passing value in index.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190227/discussion-between-sravani-and-ifsogirl).

Comment: Hi, How can use destructering syntax  if we have multiple properties in serviceRequest object.